# Redshift 'not returning any result when executing through Robot Framework automation

Tags: amazon-redshift, pyodbc, q

I am automating certain queries to fetch results from Redshift. While all other queries are running just fine, issue is with the "Describe" statement which returns a syntax error message. Following is the code:

Query:

```sql
describe schema.table;
```

Tried alternative query :

```sql
SELECT * FROM pg_table_def WHERE tablename = 'my_table' AND schemaname = 'my_schema';
```

This is not returning any value either.

Can someone suggest any other alternative please?

Automation Script framework used : Robot Framework

Comment: select from pg_tables instead. see https://chartio.com/resources/tutorials/how-to-show-list-or-describe-tables-in-amazon-redshift/

Comment: yes tried this query : SELECT * FROM pg_table_def WHERE tablename = 'my_table' AND schemaname = 'my_schema'; but its not returning any result

Comment: ok - maybe that is the question you should be asking - consider updating your question.

Comment: update my question